# document.getElementById no line feed

Tags: javascript

I've just started trying to learn javascript and have hit a problem.
The following code I expect to see my input box and button followed by 1,2,...10. Each number on a new line. What i get is the number 10 right below the box. I don't see the numbers 1,2,...9

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<style>
  #pastetext {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .enter {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function abc() {
    intext = document.getElementById("pastetext").value;
    for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
      document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = i;
    }
  }
</script>


<body>

  <input type="text" name="enter" class="enter" value="" id="pastetext" />
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="Click to Enter Data" onclick="abc();" />

  <div id="answer" style="color:red; padding-left:100px;">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

What i get is this:[enter image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxMWl.png)

Comment: A good thing to learn up front is that it's called **JavaScript**, not Java.

Comment: Why do you expect to see multiple lines if every time you **overwrite** `innerHTML` of your `div`?

Answer (score 5):

You're setting the `innerHTML` property over and over again. Setting that properly completely replaces the previous content.

You could append the text:

```
function abc(){
   var intext = document.getElementById("pastetext").value;
   var answer = document.getElementById("answer");
   answer.innerHTML = "";
   for(var i=1; i <11; i++){
       answer.innerHTML += i + " ";
   }
}
```

Note that the local variables in your function should be declared with `var`.

Comment: That worked perfect, except I want each number on it's own line. I tried "\r" instead of " ", but it didnt work.

Comment: @RobertG you're creating HTML.  HTML treats all whitespace the same (newlines are just like spaces) unless you style the container appropriately or you explicitly also add more markup to force vertical alignment. That's not a JavaScript thing, it's the way HTML/CSS work.

Comment: I'm confused about something. 

The For loop steps through 1,2,...10 and executes answer.innerHTML += i + " "; 10 times  

So why do you use += ? 
The first time through i=1 and answer.innerHTML should output 1, then the next time through 2, etc... 

I would think it would read answer.innerHTML = i + " ";

Comment: @RobertG `answer.innerHTML = i;` means, "Replace the **entire** contents of the element with `i`".  A simple assignment - the `=` operator - replaces the old value with the new value. By using `+=`, you append each value of `i` to the content.